# csrf_exempt is not working in my django project

Tags: django, twilio, django-csrf

I am using django 3.2 I am trying to use a twilio webhook on my site but still getting the error

```
403 forbidden
<p>CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.</p>


  <p>You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie
    when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons, to
    ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.</p>
  <p>If you have configured your browser to disable cookies, please
    re-enable them, at least for this site, or for “same-origin” requests.</p>
```

my view

```
@csrf_exempt
@validate_twilio_request
def webhook(request):
    return HttpResponse("something")
```

what are my doing wrong?

Comment: Quick question, to help me understand how you are testing this. From where did you copy the HTML of the error that you included in your question? Did this come directly from the Twilio logs or did you use a different method to get this output? What I'm trying to determine is the source of the 403 error. Both the `csrf_exempt` and `validate_twilio_request` decorators fail with 403. I'm wondering if the 403s you see are coming from the Twilio validator.

Comment: I figured out the issue another url before it was matching this url first and therefore was not csrf exempt and was causing the problem